# How to enable Virtualisation on ACER E1-510?

Tags: bios, virtualization, acer-aspire

I would like to enable virtualisation on acer  ACER E1-510
In the BIOS (Security section), i have this:

[image]

Comment: What processor do you have?

Comment: Intel Quad Core N3520

Comment: It supports at least VT-x. But the setting for enabling virtualization are usually not in the tab you're showing.

Comment: I cannot tell what the names of the other tabs are.  Could you please provide a screenshot which is better quality with that information?

Comment: The other tabs's titles are: "Information", "Main", "Boot" & "Exit"

Comment: In many other models and manufactures, i found this on "Security" tab